# Bibliography not printed in #TexShop

Tags: bibliographies

I am new to LaTeX. I am using TexShop 4.27. I am writing a book using article class `scrbook`. I am having problems with compiling the bibliography. I have searched this forum for possible answers, but was unsuccessful. Any suggestions are welcome. Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{scrbook}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}

\setkomafont{subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
sorting=nyt,
bibstyle=philosophy-modern,
publocformat=loccolonpub,
inbeforejournal=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You should add a description of the problems that you got.

Comment: You probably need to tell your editor to run Biber for you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 (BTW: unless you have a really good reason not to, I'd probably replace `style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, bibstyle=philosophy-modern,` with `style=philosophy-modern,` to give `biblatex-philosophy` full control over citations and bibliography). If you did that and still get errors, show us the contents of the `.blg` file.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos Bibliography does not get printed. I just get the message (Re-)run BibTex.

Comment: @moewe, your suggestion has worked! Thanks a lot.